# php to mysql update post not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

For some reason this will not update the db, the values for the db login are correct use the same inc file for all the pages. No errors, just no updates in the db. Can't seem to figure it out for the life of me.

```
<?
include("../../inc/config.inc.php");
session_start();
$loggeduser = $_SESSION['myusername'];
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:login/login.php");
}
?>
<?
$userpost = $_POST["username"];
if(is_null($userpost)) {
mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pwd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());
$server_query_sql = ("SELECT * FROM $admin_tbl WHERE username = '$loggeduser'");
$getdata = mysql_query($server_query_sql) or die("Couldn't execute the query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $getdata );
$adminuser = $row['username'];
$adminpass = $row['password'];
$adminemail = $row['email'];
mysql_close();
}
else {
$postemail = $_POST["email"];
$postpass = $_POST["password"];
$encrypted_password = md5($postpass);
mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pwd") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());
$server_query_sql = ("SELECT * FROM $admin_tbl WHERE username = '$loggeduser'");
$getdata = mysql_query($server_query_sql) or die("Couldn't execute the query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $getdata );
$adminuser = $row['username'];
$adminpass = $row['password'];
$adminemail = $row['email'];

if ($encrypted_password = $adminpass){
$query = "UPDATE $admin_tbl SET email='$postemail' WHERE username='$loggeduser'";
mysql_query($query);
}
else {
$query = "UPDATE $admin_tbl SET email='$postemail', password='$encrypted_password'     WHERE username='$loggeduser'";
    mysql_query($query);
mysql_close(); 
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../inc/login.css" />
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700);
        body {

            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .container > header h1,
        .container > header h2 {
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body><br><br>
  <div align="center">Hi <strong><? echo $loggeduser; ?></strong>!</div>
   <div class="container">
        <section class="main">
            <form class="form-3" method="post" action='<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <label for="login">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Username" value='<? echo $adminemail; ?>'>
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value='<? echo $adminpass; ?>'> 
                </p>
                <p class="clearfix">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
                </p>       
            </form>​
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How have you tried to figure it out?

Comment: start debugging by using `var_dump()`to check your UPDATE sql-statements

Comment: You are not checking for errors so it's no wonder you're not seeing any. See http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Note: The `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. It is strongly recommended to switch to using the `mysqli` or `PDO` libs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
    if ($encrypted_password = $adminpass){
```

use

```
   if ($encrypted_password == $adminpass){
```

you can fix this to see if they really equal the passwords by using

```
   echo $encrypted_password . ' ----- ' .$adminpass ;  // and see if they are same.
```

Comment: did `$adminpass` is encrypted also from database? by md5

Comment: do you mean it doesnt update both ? when if and when else if ?

Comment: you should debugg it yourself step by step , everytime echo some variable and see if its right. till you come to the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

First problem I see is `$encrypted_password = $adminpass`. Use `==` for comparison.

Comment: $userpost = $_POST["username"];